# Proving efficiency class for a time complexity function

Tags: performance, algorithm, time-complexity, proof, induction

Below is the solution but I have trouble understanding 1 part of the proof by induction part. Why can you just add + 2 to one side and +4 to the other?

We're dealing with the function `T(n) = 2n + 2`

We want to find a c such that `T(n) <= c * f(n)` for large *n*

We have `T(n) = 2n + 2` and `f(n) = n`, so we need `2n + 2 <= c * n`

We solve for *c* and get `2 + 2/n`

`2/n` is undefined at n = 0, so we pick `t >= 1`. We'll pick `t=1`, so `c=4`

Proof by induction:

```
         T(n) <= c * f(n)
     (2n + 2) <= (4)(n)
          +2     +4              <---- Don't understand
      2n + 4  <= 4n + 4
2(n + 1) + 2  <= 4(n + 1)
     T(n + 1) <= c * f(n + 1)
```

Conclusion:
2n + 2 ∈ O(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `2n+2 <= 4n`, by adding 2 to the left hand side and 4 to the right hand, you add less to the left hand, so if `2n+2  <= 4n`, definetly `2n + 2 <= 4n + 4`

So, you basically jumped from `2n+2 <= 4n` (which you know to be true from induction hypothesis) to `2n+4 <= 4n+4`, since `2<4` and `2n+2<=4n`. You later find out that the claim of the induciton hypothesis is also correct for `n+1` in the next lines.